# Example on how to write a bump method

Tags: java, queue

I have to write a command called bump with a parameter n. It should Move the nth person in the queue  to the front of the queue.

Bump should be a void method that accepts the parameter n. The implementation
is cleanest if a stack is used to store the temporarily removed names so they can be
placed back on the queue in the proper order. Alternatively, you can just adjust
pointers as needed, but be careful.

Here is what i have, but it keeps throwing a null pointer exception. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
public void bump(int n) {
        LinearNode<T> current = head;
        int i = 1;
        while (i != n) {
            current = current.getNext();

        }
        head.setElement(current.getElement());
    }
```

Comment: I would expect that you are passing the end of the list (e.g. for a list of 5 people, trying to move the 7th to the 1st spot). You need to  ensure that `current` has a next element/is not null before you try to get the next.

Answer (score 2):

The loop index is not incremented.  The while loop diverges for n != 1.